# Xamarin Mobile Geolocation Task Never Resolves

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.mobile

While using Xamarin.Mobile.Geolocator I've come across an odd bug that seems to be blocking me from resolving the Task. For example:

```
        var locator = new Geolocator ();
        if (locator.IsGeolocationAvailable) {
            Console.WriteLine ("Location Available");
            var task = locator.GetPositionAsync (10000);
            Console.WriteLine ("Task Created");
            var position = task.Result;
            Console.WriteLine ("Position Status: {0}", position.Timestamp);
            Console.WriteLine ("Position Latitude: {0}", position.Latitude);
            Console.WriteLine ("Position Longitude: {0}", position.Longitude);
        } else {
            Console.WriteLine ("newp");
        }
```

This function eventually times out on task.Result. I've attempted to debug this by setting the `info.plist` `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription` and `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` params, changing it to `.ContinueWith` lambda, tested on simulator and actual device, set timeout to 100 seconds, but it always seems to crash on timeout.

Is this a problem with my implementation or a bug in Xamarin.Mobile? I would like to continue with Xamarin.Mobile, but I'm not opposed to reverting back to native implementation.

Thanks

Comment: I have the same issue but for Android when using it indoors. Have you made any progress? For me iOS it's working ok. Do you use the latest version? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28797525/getpositionasync-does-not-return-on-real-device-when-indoors-xamarin-android

Comment: hi @Sunkas, I actually did solve the problem. It may be different for you, but I had an issue with the .Result. I was able to fix by getting rid of .Result and running it inside a block after it's truly resolved.

Comment: Ok. Could you answer your own question and paste the code you used to solve it?